# Exclude a list item from easytabs.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

I have an unordered list with various tab items:

```
                <nav class="navigation-area">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#home"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>
                            Home</a>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a href="http://example.com/blog"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>Blog</a>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a href="#profile"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                            Profile</a>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a href="#portfolio"><i class=
                            "fa fa-briefcase"></i> Portfolio</a>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a href="#resume"><i class=
                            "fa fa-file-text"></i> Resume</a>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a href="#contact"><i class=
                            "fa fa-envelope"></i> Contact</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
```

I am trying to get the "Blog" element to link to a site instead of be used as a tab. however the easytabs is breaking the page as it is unable to find the referenced element in the code. How can I skip including this element in the easy tabs? The way I am initializing easytabs is like so:

```
    $('#tab-container').easytabs({
         updateHash: false
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/6dqc6r4j/1/

the element LI in which is url change in SPAN tag

```
<span>
    <a href="http://example.com/blog"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>Blog</a>
</span>
```

Comment: Uh... Your tabs are broken. I see both the HTML and CSS data when it should only show the active tabs content. This is the exact problem I have when using a link instead of an anchor.

Comment: In Firefox works. The problem is visible in Chrome. When I tested did not use chrome.

Comment: Of course. I assumed that if it works in Firefox that will work well in Chrome. I was wrong

Comment: He also works in Chrome. The problem is when you mix http and https protocols when adding javascript and css files. Also JSFIDDLE seems to have a problem with easjtabs plugin. Please see https://github.com/maksa9/easjtabs. Working in my Chrome